# How can I use QOpenGLWidget on Android?

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

When I try to compile with current **Android SDK tools 25.2.2** standard example from Qt 5.6 - "Cube OpenGL ES 2.0 example", then it works good on Win/Linux, but black screen on Android 7.0 - API 24.

The same behavior occur when I put object of QOpenGLWidget on MainWindow - black screen on Android 7.0 - API 24.

Application output in both cases:

```
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): ERROR: Valid GLSL but not GLSL ES
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libQtGUI.so: #define mediump
W libQtGUI.so: #define highp
W libQtGUI.so: #line 1
W libQtGUI.so: attribute highp vec3 vertexCoord;attribute highp vec2 textureCoord;varying highp vec2 uv;uniform highp mat4 vertexTransform;uniform highp mat3 textureTransform;void main() {   uv = (textureTransform * vec3(textureCoord,1.0)).xy;   gl_Position = vertexTransform * vec4(vertexCoord,1.0);}
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: Valid GLSL but not GLSL ES
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
```

But when I downgrade to **Android SDK tools 25.1.7** from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.1.7-windows.zip then QOpenGLWidget works fine on Android only on MainWindow, but but it does not show anything any other QDialog if it contains QOpenGLWidget.

Is this possible to use QOpenGLWidget on Android, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error sounds a lot like code is compiled to use desktop GL. I don't know GLWidget code at all but Qt build systems has opengl version/flavor select during library build. The errors sounds a lot like your Qt was build with desktop opengl but android only provide opengl ES. In desktop side you could check which opengl flavor is actually used. It might only work in linux/windows because they provide libraries for both opengl flavors.